# Caret no longer visible within contenteditable body tag after inserting a text node programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I'm using Mozilla Firefox (83.0) on a Windows 10 Pro machine.

With a simple body tag with contenteditable attribute enabled, my caret disappears when I insert a text node. I did this exact same test on Chrome version 87.0.4280.88 and it doesn't behave this way

Here is a demo of this. Also you can find the fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/dg47mkat/1/

```js
setTimeout(function(){ 
    let range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    let element = document.createElement('span');
    range.insertNode(element);
 }, 10000);
```

```html
<html>
<body contenteditable="true">
This is a test
</body>
</html>
```

Make sure to click somewhere within the text to see the caret being displayed, and wait the allotted timeout to run. After the insertion of the node, the caret is no longer visible unless you press on the arrow key or type a character.

Also please note, when there is text selection this does not occur.

Update 2020-12-11:12:40
I assumed that it would behave like it does in chrome, which is that the caret stays where it currently is, as is.

Comment: All the ContentEditable API implementations have their own quirks, this seems to be one of those in Firefox. But what is your actual question? Probably you want to show the caret somewhere after inserting the empty element, but where exactly?

Comment: I have updated my question to mention what i would have expected it to do.

Comment: It looks like you'd need to add `range.collapse(); ` after created the element. If you're actually adding text to the new element, you can pass `true` to `.collapse` to put the cursor at the begin of the new element, Omitting the argument or setting it to `false` moves the cursor to the end of the new element.

Comment: @Teemu Although i didnt mention it, ideally selection of text would remain selected, I don't think collapse would work in that specific case. Indeed if we focus specifically on the workflow that I mentioned without selection then this would solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem in a way that works for both unselected and selected text.

Note: The change that I made was to clone the range and then re-apply that specific range after. It looks like in Firefox this is required, but in Chrome it is not. (refer to OP for version details)

```js
 setTimeout(function(){
  let range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  let clonedRange = range.cloneRange();
  let element = document.createElement('span');
  range.insertNode(element);
  
  let selection = document.getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(clonedRange);
 }, 10000);
```

```html
<html>
<body contenteditable="true" id="mybody">This is a test</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "_Although i didnt mention ..._" Well, you didn't, but I guess any better suggestions won't occur, this is it.

Comment: For your future questions, please keep the current line when introducing the problem (that's excellent!), but also always ask an actual question, explain in details what you need, that way you don't have to find the final solution by yourself, and other users don't have to guess your question.